# Home Network Proxy Server

Tags: networking, router, proxy, python

First, my setup:

1. a cable modem and a Fritz!Box connecting me to the Internet
2. a PC connected via network cable to the Fritz Box
3. multiple Wi-Fi devices, also connected to the Fritz Box

Here is what I want to achieve:
I want to set up something like a network proxy server on a separate machine, that intercepts and (potentially) relays ALL traffic between any device in my network and the Internet. 
I don't care about traffic between devices in my network. 
I don't want to be limited to messages on a certain protocol / port / IP address. 
My main goal is to learn about networking / protocols, etc., and implement multiple applications / play around on that proxy server.  Examples could be:

- Collect statistics about all IPs / ports that had ongoing communication (so, basically forwarding all traffic, and doing some counts)
- block some traffic (e.g., prevent the kids from accessing stuff that they shouldn't see, based on IP address. 
  Prevent software to send privacy-related data about me.)
- warn about new devices in my home network (e.g., somebody misusing my Wi-Fi)
- change messages before forwarding them (e.g., adding text to web content coming in)
- send own messages to either a server on the Internet, or to one of the connected devices (e.g., collected usage statistics to be displayed in a web interface)
- many more ...

Assuming that I have a Unix (/ Linux) machine available:

- Network setup: What network topology would be needed? 
  Where in my network do I need to place the proxy machine?
- Settings: What do I need to configure on the proxy, in order to receive and forward all incoming and outgoing traffic? I do NOT want to change settings on the host devices. Connecting them to the network should be enough.
- Programmability: What do I need to set up additionally, in order to read / modify / write / send / block messages/packets using Python?
- Limitations: Would such a setup mean a serious impact on my network speed?

--- EDIT ---
I made some progress and created a python script that accepts incoming connections. Furthermore, I set the wifi connection of another machine to use the first one as a gateway. I successfully receive messages now, but the problem is, that I don't have any idea where they actually should be sent to. I would assume that I have to change the socket configuration and use transparent proxies, but I didn't find much about how to actually do this in python. Also, my script runs currently on a mac, so maybe not every option for sockets is available.

Below my current snippet:

```
import socket


def received_from(sock, timeout):
    dt = ""
    sock.settimeout(timeout)
    try:
        while True:
            dt = sock.recv(4096)
            if not dt:
                break
            dt = + dt
    except:
        pass
    return dt


def hexdump(data, length=16):
    filter = ''.join([(len(repr(chr(x))) == 3) and chr(x) or '.' for x in range(256)])
    lines = []
    digits = 4 if isinstance(data, str) else 2
    for c in range(0, len(data), length):
        chars = data[c:c+length]
        hex = ' '.join(["%0*x" % (digits, (x)) for x in chars])
        printable = ''.join(["%s" % (((x) <= 127 and filter[(x)]) or '.') for x in chars])
        lines.append("%04x  %-*s  %s\n" % (c, length*3, hex, printable))
    print(''.join(lines))


s = socket.socket()
print("Socket successfully created")

try:
    port = 12222

    s.bind(('', port))
    print("socket bound to port {}".format(port))

    s.listen(5)
    print("socket listening")

    print("proxy sock: {}".format(s.getsockname()))

    while True:
        try:
            c, addr = s.accept()
            print("got connection from {}".format(addr))
            print("client peer: {}".format(c.getpeername()))
            print("client sock: {}".format(c.getsockname()))

            data = received_from(c, 3)
            hexdump(data)
            print()

            c.send("Connection received. Thanks and bye!".encode('utf-8'))

            c.close()
        except Exception as e:
            c.close()
            raise e

except Exception as e:
    s.close()
    raise e
```

Comment: OK, I will try the edit and notify you again.

Comment: @Tim_Stewart I tried to adapt the question. Could you please have a look?

Comment: Looks good to me, it has 4 reopen votes as I write this.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some suggestions:

1) First of all, get access to your home gateway's (FritzBox) admin page. Usually  is a username / password connection via browser to 192.168.1.1. Review settings of WAN, LAN, Wifi and read about it.

2) Install linux and commandline tools :  tcpdump, netstat, nc, telnet

3) Have another machine windows / linux with user interface, install there Wireshark

4) Try to develop some simple [python socket level programs](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/socket-programming-python/) (python socket libraries fit nicely on C socket API's)

5) Record traffic between programs on different computers with tcpdump, and examine packages with Wireshark

6) Try adding proxy server (dedicated machine) to your home LAN network.

7) Install programs like Apache web server, CuteFTP, SMPT Relay, MiniDLNA etc ...

You can use my [cheetsheat](https://docs.google.com/document/pub?id=1ehLgBv2LtX_fPpUk7qIcdv39t56zUmcRTxnE_HU15mE) for linux to experiment with network related stuff

8) Try to create your own SSL certificates, to secure connections between computers in your network.

Answers to your questions:

Network setup:  proxy is placed on network like any other machine. But all machine's refer to it (use it as "gateway").

Settings: All machines need to be informed of a proxy (port, address) via configuration parameter.

Programmability: Nothing. it will work out of the box.

Limitations: Would such a setup mean a serious impact on my network speed? No.

Comment: Thx! Steps 1-5 I did already. Step 6 is what I'm currently thinking about. Also, if I have to inform all devices about a proxy / gateway, I can't warn about new devices, correct? The other use cases would probably still work though.

Comment: Setting proxy is operation for HTTP / HTTPS / FTP protocol only. This a layer 6 application. There  is nothing on lower levels of TCP/IP that is knows as "proxy". It's a application thing, and client applications (browser, wget, curl) can choose to use proxy or not (and of course have a working connection to outside world). It's a security design decision. Clients need to be aware of proxy.. And proxy machine can be the only one having access to internet. Proxy server is just a machine, regular host. Could be in DMZ zone.

Comment: I made a few steps, and receive messages from clients, but I have no idea, how to obtain the target IP and forward the message there...

Comment: I do not understand. Obtain target IP of who ? Client, proxy machine, target host ? Proxy is not set on the router. It's configured on machine of your choice, then your client on another machine is informed of proxy machine via setting ( export http_proxy=http://server-ip:port/.  Then the client software on your client machine redirect HTTP traffic only (port 80) to this proxy machine. In this picture, what IP you cannot obtain?

Comment: First a clarification: I don't want to restrict to HTTP or similar only, but forward all TCP/IP traffic. I edited my question with a sample script to show what I currently have. Original scenario: Machine A in my local network communicates via my router to different servers in the internet. Modified scenario: Machine B in my local network runs the above script. Machine A sets Machine B as its gateway. Traffic that was directed to some internet server before is now directed to Machine B. From B I want to send it to the internet server that it was intended for on behalf of A.

Comment: Result should be, that Machine B acts as a gateway for Machine A in both directions, no matter to which server Machine A wants to communicate. All examples that I found only worked with a fixed server adress. I found a concept called a "transparent proxy", which sounds like what I want to use, but I didn't find any examples.

Comment: What you're proposing is a piece of software on network layer 6 - application layer, that sniffs traffic. You must manually configure all of this to work. And it will work only for TCP/IP sockets, this is clear from your python code. There's a lot of communication (advertisments and so on, UPD traffic) that is left out. If your goal is to learn about network, starting on layer 6 (app layer) is most visual but perhaps it might give you wrong impressions.

Comment: I understand what you mean. I guess, I'd have to approach this whole thing in multiple iterations and start with something simpler first. Which would also mean, I should pass all the rest of the traffic, e.g. UDP, on without intercepting it. 
For learning lower layers, I probably have to work with raw sockets and similar stuff, correct?